# How to pull data from table1's ID and place it into table2's FOREIGN KEY via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, the comment system works, I tried putting different articlecIDs and it adds a comment to a specific article. Now, I want to make when I add comment let's say to "Microsoft" article it publishes itself, without me adding a ID into query. If you don't understand what I'm trying to do, let's say I want to do this like implicitly, not explicitly:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, name, articlecID) VALUES ('$comment', '$username', 1)
```

Now I want a '$articlecID' variable instead of number '1' inside query..

I tried getting data from hidden field inside my HTML, and putting it into PHP like this:

```
$articlecID = e($_POST['articlecID']);
```

### # e() stands for function of real_escape. #

I tried also putting ID but nothing.. Anyone can fix this?

```
<?php

  # Starting session. #
    session_start();
  # Starting session. #

  # Connection to database. #
    $db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3305', 'root', '', 'assignmentnews');
  # Connection to database. #

  # Let's declare some variables. #
    $username = "";
    $errors = array();
  # Let's declare some variables. #

  # Call the register() function if register_btn is clicked. #
    if(isset($_POST['register_btn']))
    {
      register();
    }
  # Call the register() function if register_btn is clicked. #

  # Register function. #
    function register()
    {
      # Let's use here 'global' keyword to make these declared variables available outside function. #
        global $db, $errors, $username;
      # Let's use here 'global' keyword to make these declared variables available outside function. #

      # Recieve all input values from the form. Let's call e() / escape string function. #
        $username = e($_POST['username']);
        $password_01 = e($_POST['pwd']);
        $password_02 = e($_POST['pwd-confirmation']);
      # Recieve all input values from the form. Let's call e() / escape string function. #

      # Form validation. Let's make sure that form is correctly filled. #
        if(empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required."); }
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) { array_push($errors, "Invalid characters in username field."); }
        if(empty($password_01)) { array_push($errors, "Password field can't be empty."); }
        if(empty($password_02)) { array_push($errors, "Re-entering password field can't be empty, either."); }
      # Form validation. Let's make sure that form is correctly filled. #

      # Let's register user if there are no errors inside form. #
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
          # Encrypt password before storing it inside database. #
            $password = md5($password_01);
          # Encrypt password before storing it inside database. #

          if(isset($_POST['usertype']))
          {
            $usertype = e($_POST['usertype']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, pwd, usertype) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$usertype')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['success'] = "New user successfully created.";
            header("Location: ../registration/login.php");
          }
          else
          {
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, pwd, usertype) VALUES ('$username', '$password', 'user')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

            # Let's get ID of the created user. #
              $logged_in_user_ID = mysqli_insert_id($db);
            # Let's get ID of the created user. #

              # Let's put logged in user in session. #
                $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_ID);
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in.";
                header("Location: ../user.php?loggedIn");
              # Let's put logged in user in session. #
          }
        }
      # Let's register user if there are no errors inside form. #
    }

    # Function for getting users ID. #
      function getUserById($id)
      {
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $user;
      }
    # Function for getting users ID. #

    # Escape string function. #
      function e($val)
      {
        global $db;
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
      }
    # Escape string function. #
  # Register function. #

  # Display error function. #
    function display_error()
    {
      global $errors;
      if(count($errors) > 0)
      {
        echo '<div class="error">';
          foreach($errors as $error)
          {
            echo $error . '<br>';
          }
          echo '</div>';
      }
    }
  # Display error function. #

  # Let's make an algorithm when person types url like: user.php into browser they are unable to access page if not logged in. #
    function isLoggedIn()
    {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  # Let's make an algorithm when person types url like: user.php into browser they are unable to access page if not logged in. #

  # Let's make an function if user click logout button, logout action happens. #
    if(isset($_GET['logout']))
    {
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['user']);
      header("Location: login.php");
    }
  # Let's make an function if user click logout button, logout action happens. #

  # Let's call the login() function if the login button is clicked. #
    if(isset($_POST['login_user']))
    {
      login();
    }

    function login()
    {
      # Let's use here 'global' keyword to make these declared variables available outside function. #
        global $db, $username, $errors;
      # Let's use here 'global' keyword to make these declared variables available outside function. #

      # Recieve all input values from the form. Let's call e() / escape string function. #
        $username = e($_POST['username']);
        $password = e($_POST['pwd']);
      # Recieve all input values from the form. Let's call e() / escape string function. #

      # Form validation. Let's make sure that form is correctly filled. #
        if(empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username field is required. It can't be empty."); }
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) { array_push($errors, "Invalid characters in username field."); }
        if(empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password field is required. It can't be empty."); }
      # Form validation. Let's make sure that form is correctly filled. #

      # Let's attempt login if there are no errors on form. #
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
          $password = md5($password);
          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND pwd='$password'";
          $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

          # User found. #
            if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1)
          # User found. #
          {
            # Let's check if person is admin or user. #
              $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
              if($logged_in_user['usertype'] == 'admin')
              {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are logged in as admin.";
                header("Location: ../admin.php");
              }
              else
              {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in as user.";
                header("Location: ../user.php");
              }
            # Let's check if person is admin or user. #
          }
          else
          {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination.");
          }
        }
      # Let's attempt login if there are no errors on form. #
    }
  # Let's call the login() function if the login button is clicked. #

  # Let's add isAdmin function. #
    function isAdmin()
    {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['usertype'] == 'admin')
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  # Let's add isAdmin function. #

  # Algorithm for saveChanges button-submit. #
    if(isset($_POST['saveChanges']))
    {
      saveChangesArticle();
    }
  # Algorithm for saveChanges button-submit. #

  # Save changes function. #
    function saveChangesArticle()
    {
      global $db, $errors;
      $headline = e($_POST['headline']);
      $storyline = e($_POST['storyText']);
      $authorUsername = e($_POST['authorUser']);
      $timestampDate = e($_POST['date']);

      if(empty($headline)) { array_push($errors, "Headline / Title field is required."); }
      if(empty($storyline)) { array_push($errors, "Storyline / Text field is required."); }
      if(empty($authorUsername)) { array_push($errors, "Author / Username field is required."); }
      if(empty($timestampDate)) { array_push($errors, "Date field is required."); }

      if(count($errors) == 0)
      {
        $query = "INSERT INTO newsmodule (headline, storyline, username, timestamp)
                                  VALUES ('$headline', '$storyline', '$authorUsername', '$timestampDate')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        header("Location: admin.php?ArticleAddedSuccessfully");
        exit();
      }
      else
      {
        echo("Error: Creating article failed.");
      }
    }
  # Save changes function. #

  # Function for viewing news. #
    function viewNews()
    {
      global $db;
      $query = "SELECT * FROM newsmodule ORDER BY timestamp";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
      if (!$result)
      {
        echo "Error selecting headline from database.";
        exit();
      }
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
        echo "<div style='margin-left: 0; width: 100%;' class='jumbotron'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
        {
          echo "<h1><br>" . $row->headline . "</h1>";
          echo "<hr>";
          echo "<p>" . $row->storyline . "</p>";
          echo "<hr>";
          echo "<h5 class='pull-right'>" . $row->username . "</h5>";
          echo "<p>" . $row->timestamp . "</p>";
          echo "<hr>";
          echo showCommentArea($row->id);
          echo "<a data-target='#postComment' class='text-white dropdown-toggle btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' type='button'>";
          echo  "Publish a Comment";
          echo "</a>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "No headlines in database.";
      }
    }
  # Function for inserting comments. #

    function addComment()
    {
      global $db, $errors, $username;
      $comment = $_POST['comment-text'];
      $username = $_POST['commenter-username'];
      $articlecID = $_POST['articlecID']; # Getting value from input name attr #
      if(count($errors) == 0)
      {
        $query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, name, articlecID)
                  VALUES ('$comment', '$username', '$articlecID')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        header("Location: ./admin.php?successMessage");
      }
    }
  # Function for inserting comments. #

  # Function for joining tables. #

  # Function for joining tables. #

  if(isset($_POST['saveChanges02'])){
    addComment();
  }

  # Post comment function. #
    function showCommentArea($id)
    {
      global $db, $errors, $username;
      if(count($errors) == 0)
      {
        $query = "SELECT comment, name FROM comments
                  INNER JOIN newsmodule ON comments.articlecID=newsmodule.id WHERE $id = newsmodule.id";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if(!$result)
        {
          echo "SQL Query ERROR: !ERR_SQL_QUERY_01";
          exit();
        }
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          echo "<div>";
          echo "<h4>";
          echo "Comments:";
          echo "</h4>";
          echo "<br>";
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            echo "<p class='text-danger' style='font-weight: bold;'>" . $row->name . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $row->comment . "</p>";
          }
          echo "</div>";
        }
      }
    }
  # Post comment function. #
```

```
HTML:

  <article class="news-review">
            <header>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td><p><?php viewNews(); ?>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="postComment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="postCommentLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="postCommentLabel">Post a Comment</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post" action="admin.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Comment Text Area</label>
                          <textarea name="comment-text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment Text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Commenter Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="commenter-username" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="articlecID" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" name="saveChanges02" class="btn btn-danger">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </p></td>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </header>
          </article>
```

I expect when I hit publish comment inside article it publishes and adds a new id inside newsmodule table - table for articles, and a new foreign key - articlecID inside comments table - table for articles. Thank you!

EDIT:
In here:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, name, articlecID) VALUES ('$comment', '$username', '')";
```

Inside empty field I tried to put a column from other table, but nothing.
Like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, name, articlecID) VALUES ('$comment', '$username', 'newsmodule.id')";
```

Comment: `$articlecID = ` - and how did you try and insert this into your query then? Show us the actual code, please, not just snippets that lack context.

Comment: Btw.: Use prepared statements for queries with variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php. Also, do not use `global` but instead use parameters. Please [edit] your question  to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Explain in detail what the problem is.

Comment: @04FS Here's a whole code, I didn't put it because it has whole system in one file, which is, I know, wrong thing to do sometimes, but since I'm beginner, never had a job and it's a practice for me, it's okay.

Comment: @Progman I want a ID of Foreign Key instead of hard-coding a number inside that query. Okay now?

Comment: @ravenousHydra You have to show the HTML code with the forms as well since these define which values are send to your PHP script.

Comment: @Progman HTML added as well.

Comment: @ravenousHydra You have the HTML code `<input type="hidden" name="articlecID" />` for a hidden field for the `articlecID`, which is good. But how do you fill this field with a value? You usually have the attribute `value="abcdef"` to set the value of an input field, why do you not have it here?

Comment: @Progman You mean, I should put a PHP code inside that value="<?php ?>" , or some random value?

Comment: @ravenousHydra You can add any value you want, but most likely you want to add the id of the article so the PHP script for the comment will receive this article ID.

Comment: @Progman But, shouldn't that be used from name attr? And index it inside PHP script like: $id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: @ravenousHydra `name="..."` is for the name of the `<input>` field, `value="..."` is for the value of the `<input>` field. Please check https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php for how to work with HTML forms and how data is send between the browser (where the HTML is rendered/displayed) and server (where the PHP script is running).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, name, articlecID) VALUES ('$comment', '$username', (SELECT id from newsmodule where ....))";
```

Comment: This query has major security issues and should not be used, used prepared statements or placeholders.

Comment: Obviously it would be up to the OP to sanitize, I offered the suggestion - not the finished code, but thank you for pointing out the obvious

Comment: Another option for him would be to use PDO, but that was not his original scripting...